# SQL Query (complex)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure e.g.

```
id  |  group  |  parent  |  value
1       123        1         10
2       123        1         25
3       224        1         12
4       224        1         22
5       225        2         18
6       225        2         10
7       326        2         18
8       326        2         35
```

Now i need to grab the highest number of each group and combine the result per parent column so the wanted result would be like the following:

```
group  |  parent  |   value
123         1          47
225         2          53
```

I can group them by parent but don't know how to group them additionally by group within the parent.

Thank you

Comment: `GROUP BY parent, group`

Comment: OK but i need to find the total of the highest values as well :(

Comment: Are the example results actually the results you want given the example data? I don't understand how you are getting those values: 47, 53, etc.

Comment: e.g. 47 is a sum of 25 and 22 .. the values with ID 2 and 4 as they are the HIGHEST values within the group/parent. Hope this makes sense more now. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a nested query like this:

```
select
    parent,
    sum(max_of_group_value)
from (
    select
        parent,
        group
        max(value) as max_of_group_value)
    from <table>
    group by
        parent,
        group
) t
group by
    parent;
```

Alternatively, use a CTE for the subquery thus:

```
;with t as (
    select
        parent,
        group
        max(value) as max_of_group_value)
    from <table>
    group by
        parent,
        group
)
select
    parent,
    sum(max_of_group_value)
from t
group by
    parent;
```

Now look closely at whatever presentation of the query you prefer; isn't the code written exactly as you described the problem in your (question and comment combined)?  That is the key to writing code that is *obviously* correct, and readable.

Comment: Hmm the intellisense says "invalid column name for all columns. Also i don't see the FROM tablename statement ... sorry for the stupid question but where i should put that portion? Thx

Comment: Somehow i managed the code to work but it's not complete yet as i need to display the group column as well.

Comment: SELECT
 sub.parent,
    SUM(MaxValue)
FROM(
SELECT data.group, data.parent, groupedValue.MaxValue
FROM MyTable AS data
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT group, MAX(value) AS MaxValue
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY group) groupedValue 
ON data.group = groupedTime.group 
AND data.value = groupedTime.MaxValue
) sub
GROUP BY
    parent

Comment: @ElizabethDimova - For Parent 1, there are 2 groups, 123 and 224. How did you decide to show 123 and not 224. Do you want a minimum group value?

Comment: i think that it's the very first group value e.g. for the parent 1 i can show the group 123 with ID = 1. Thank you